# Bootstrap white space between boxes

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new on bootstrap trying to improve my skills, i just got stuck, i have 6 boxes, three left side and three right side, my question is why there is space between box number '4' and '5' when i'm on 'sm, md,lg' sizes ? how can i put box number 5 under box number 4 without blank space ? and is there away to take away those 'white space' and still make this work like this ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  
 .box{
  width:30%;
  height:250px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }
   .boxx{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: solid white 1px;
  }
   .bo{
  width:50%;
  height:550px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="boxx mx-auto">
            white space 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box mx-auto">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="bo mx-auto">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box mx-auto">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="boxx mx-auto">
            white space 
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="box mx-auto">
          5
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, you're using Bootstrap v4, `col-xs-*` classes don't exist in version 4 anymore, you should instead use `col-*`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  
 .box{
  width:30%;
  height:250px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }
   .bo{
  width:50%;
  height:550px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box mx-auto">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="bo mx-auto">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box mx-auto">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="box mx-auto">
          5
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for answering, could you also show how to have boxes '2, 4, 5' under eachother now there is white space between box 4 and 5 when you see it with desktop size

Comment: It's easy. You just need to write one separate row for 2, 4, 5 division, then they all assign one by one. Write another row for the divisions you wanted show in other side.

Comment: your previous code was good but just between 4 and 5 was space, now you changed alot.

Comment: wait...2 minutes.

Comment: @walee Now check it. There's no space between 4 and 5.

Comment: it looks fine now if i want to have everything in center, i just add margins ?

Comment: In bigger screens it still has the blank space between 4 & 5

Comment: @walee you can use bootstrap class `text-center` to center the division. Please mark it if you're happy.

Comment: @IvanS95 don't look at the old code. Please look at the first code snippet.